# Если значение пусто то берем прошлое

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Как реализовать что-бы при цикли если значение пустое нужно взять его из прошлого раза

```
$table = $html_product->find('#product_teh tbody',0);
$html = str_get_html($table);
$rows = $html->find("tr");
$rcount = count($rows);

for($idx = 0; $idx < $rcount; $idx+=2){
    $name = $rows[$idx]->find("td.feature_block_name",0)->plaintext;
    $fname  = $rows[$idx + 1]->find("td.feature_name",0)->plaintext;
    $fvalue = $rows[$idx + 1]->find("td.feature_value", 0)->plaintext;

    $theData[] = $name."|".$fname."|".$fvalue;
}

$theData = implode($theData,PHP_EOL);
```

Вот что сейчас получаю

```
Конструкция|Дисплей|Есть
Основные|Вид|газовый
|Камера сгорания|закрытая
|Объем бака|8 л
|Теплообменник|Есть
|Тип подогрева горячей воды|проточный
```

Вот что нужно получить

```
Конструкция|Дисплей|Есть
Основные|Вид|газовый
Основные|Камера сгорания|закрытая
Основные|Объем бака|8 л
Основные|Теплообменник|Есть
Основные|Тип подогрева горячей воды|проточный
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$name = $rows[$idx]->find("td.feature_block_name",0)->plaintext ?: $name;
```

Это синоним такого выражения:

```
if ($rows[$idx]->find("td.feature_block_name",0)->plaintext) {
    $name = $rows[$idx]->find("td.feature_block_name",0)->plaintext;
} else {
    $name = $name;
}
```

Comment: ?: я даже не знал о нем ! 
Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста. Дописал, что означает